# How do I exclude *.spec.mjs using c8?

Tags: mocha.js, code-coverage, ecmascript-next

I have the following...

App.mjs

```
import express from "express";
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

class CommunicationsApplication{
  constructor() {
    this.app = CommunicationsApplication.getExpress();
    this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World!')
    })

    this.app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
  }
  static getExpress(){
    return express()
  }
}
```

App.spec.mjs

```
import {CommunicationsApplication} from "./App.mjs";
import sinon from "sinon";
import {expect} from "chai";

it('Testing to see if test works', () => {
  const result = {
    get: sinon.fake(),
    listen: sinon.fake()
  }
  sinon.stub(CommunicationsApplication, 'getExpress').callsFake(()=>result)
  new CommunicationsApplication();
  expect(result.get.callCount).to.eq(1);
  expect(result.listen.callCount).to.eq(1);
})
```

package.json

```
"type": "module",
...
"test": "c8 --check-coverage true mocha --recursive './lib/**/*.spec.mjs' --require esm"
```

But when I run I see....

```
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |   88.57 |      100 |      50 |   88.57 |                   
 App.mjs      |   80.95 |      100 |      50 |   80.95 | 8,12,16-17        
 App.spec.mjs |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
ERROR: Coverage for lines (88.57%) does not meet global threshold (90%)
```

How do I ignore `App.spec.mjs` so that I get the correct 80.95

Comment: try `-x`  or `--exclude` with list ["App.spec.mjs"]

Comment: I need this for all spec files